# ¿Cómo puedo agregar el numero de paginas en el PDF generado con la librería html2pdf javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, html2pdf

Tengo una consulta deseo agregar un pie de pagina a mi documento PDF generado con la librería html2pdf el cual simplemente debe de mostrar el numero de paginas que tiene el documento generado, he buscado información pero no he encontrado algo relevante, les agradecería mucho por su ayuda

```
download() {
  const contenido = document.getElementById('capture')
  const ajustes = {
    margin: 0.63,
    filename: 'test.pdf',
    image: { type: 'jpeg', quality: 0.98 },
    html2canvas: { scale: 3, letterRendering: true },
    jsPDF: { unit: 'cm', format: 'letter', orientation: 'portrait' },
  }
  Html2pdf().set(ajustes).from(contenido).save()
}
```

Comment: Preguntando a san google, llegué a [este tutorial](https://codingshiksha.com/javascript/html2pdf-js-example-to-add-page-numbers-at-top-in-pdf-document-using-javascript-full-project-for-beginners/), donde se sugiere obtener cada página para agregar el número. Inténtalo y, en caso de errores, edita la pregunta para poner el nuevo código y trataremos de ayudarte sobre algo más concreto.

Comment: Muchas gracias por la ayuda

Answer (score 0):

agragar paginacion al final de la pagina

documentacion [introducir la descripción del enlace aquí](https://www.lawebdelprogramador.com/foros/PHP/2125356-Libreria-html2pdf.js.html)

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
    // Escuchamos el click del botón
    const $boton = document.querySelector("#print");
    $boton.addEventListener("click", () => {
        const $elementoParaConvertir = document.querySelector('#imprimir'); // <-- Aquí puedes elegir cualquier elemento del DOM
        html2pdf()
            .set({
                margin: 0.2,
                filename: 'notas.pdf',
                image: {
                    type: 'jpeg',
                    quality: 0.98
                },
                html2canvas: {
                    scale: 5, // A mayor escala, mejores gráficos, pero más peso
                    letterRendering: true,
                },
                jsPDF: {
                    unit: "in",
                    format: "letter",
                    orientation: 'portrait' // landscape o portrait
                },
            })
            //codigo para paginar 
.from($elementoParaConvertir).toPdf().get('pdf').then(function(pdf) {
        var totalPages = pdf.internal.getNumberOfPages();
        for (i = 1; i <= totalPages; i++) {
            pdf.setPage(i);
            pdf.setFontSize(10);
            pdf.text('Page ' + i + ' de ' + totalPages, (pdf.internal.pageSize.getWidth() / 2.3), (pdf.internal.pageSize.getHeight() - 0.8));
        }
    })
                .save()
                .catch(err => console.log(err));
        } );
    });
```

Comment: Saludos, ¿cómo ayuda esto al usuario? ¿Qué has cambiado? Por favor, explícalo para que sea de utilidad. ¡Muchas gracias!